# Grafana - each value of a text/label column creates a new column for all other fields/column

Tags: grafana

I have a PostgreSQL DB table with following fields:

- time
- location
- metric1
- metric2 ...

I want to have a table with two filterable columns: time and location.
Time is a timestamp value and location has normal string value inside it (e.g. NYC,SF,Boston...).

Unfortunately, Grafana table plugin turns each value of the column location into a new column for metrics metric1 and metric2.
Thus the table looks as following:

- time
- metric1 [location-value1]
- metric2 [location-value1]
- metric1 [location-value2]
- metric2 [location-value2]
- metric1 [location-value...]
- metric2 [location-value...]
- metric1 [location-valueN]
- metric2 [location-valueN]

As the location column has >400 values, this turns the table into a table with 2000-3000 columns and I only need a few of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by using "Show as table" instead of "Show as timeseriees" as one of the config options